# Creating Sort Index takes 96% of query time even without any ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have this query:

```
SELECT itr.recipe_id,
   SUM(itr.weight),
   SUM(aprice_weight),
   SUM(itr.weight+aprice_weight) AS score
FROM
  (SELECT itfin.id AS flyer_item_id,
          itfin.flyer_id,
          MAX(itfin.max_weight) AS aprice_weight,
          itfin.ingredient_id
   FROM
     (SELECT MAX(price_weight) AS max_weight,
             flyer_items.id,
             flyer_items.flyer_id,
             ingredient_to_flyer_item.ingredient_id
      FROM flyer_items
      JOIN ingredient_to_flyer_item ON flyer_items.id = ingredient_to_flyer_item.flyer_item_id
      WHERE flyer_items.flyer_id IN (2)
      GROUP BY ingredient_to_flyer_item.flyer_item_id) AS itfin
   JOIN ingredient_to_flyer_item ON itfin.id = ingredient_to_flyer_item.flyer_item_id
   GROUP BY itfin.ingredient_id) AS itf
INNER JOIN `ingredient_to_recipe` AS `itr` ON `itf`.`ingredient_id` = `itr`.`ingredient_id`
GROUP BY `itr`.`recipe_id`
ORDER BY `score` DESC
LIMIT 12
```

But even without the ORDER BY clause, execution time is still the same, around 350ms. I tried looking at the indexes to see what I can do, but nothing worked so far. Not even putting a bigger value for SORT_BUFFER_SIZE in MySQL settings.

The profiler tells me that a single Create Sort Index (out of 3) takes 96% of the query time.

Here is the EXPLAIN result:

```
| id | select_type | table                    | partitions | type   | possible_keys           | key           | key_len | ref                      | rows | filtered | extra                                        |
|----|-------------|--------------------------|------------|--------|-------------------------|---------------|---------|--------------------------|------|----------|----------------------------------------------|
| 1  | PRIMARY     | <derived2>               | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                     | 583  | 100.00   | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
| 1  | PRIMARY     | itr                      | NULL       | ref    | recipe_id,ingredient_id | ingredient_id | 4       | itf.ingredient_id        | 35   | 100.00   | NULL                                         |
| 1  | PRIMARY     | r                        | NULL       | eq_ref | id                      | id            | 4       | metadata2.itr.recipe_id  | 1    | 10.00    | Using where                                  |
| 2  | DERIVED     | <derived3>               | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                     | 246  | 100.00   | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
| 2  | DERIVED     | ingredient_to_flyer_item | NULL       | ref    | flyer_item_id           | flyer_item_id | 4       | itfin.id                 | 2    | 100.00   | Using index                                  |
| 3  | DERIVED     | flyer_items              | NULL       | ALL    | id_2,id,flyer_id        | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                     | 104  | 100.00   | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 3  | DERIVED     | ingredient_to_flyer_item | NULL       | ref    | flyer_item_id           | flyer_item_id | 4       | metadata2.flyer_items.id | 2    | 100.00   | NULL                                         |
```

Any help to speed this query up would be so appreciated. Thank you!

### UPDATE

Link to .sql demo tables: https://nofile.io/f/F4YSEu8DWmT/meta.zip

Comment: Are you sure that the query is correct? The partial GROUP BY's looks scary but it is hard to tell without the keys for the tables.

Comment: @Lennart Yes, it works. There is 2 GROUP BY only because I needed the biggets value of 2 different tables/columns.

Comment: What I mean is - for example - whether `flyer_items.id, flyer_items.flyer_id` is functionally dependent of `ingredient_to_flyer_item.flyer_item_id`. If not, your query may be non deterministic.

Comment: Please provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` for each table involved in the query.

Comment: @WillemRenzema I've updated the query for a more simple one without the recipes table (but still slow), and added the link to demo tables and data on which run the query. There was too many tables and columns to display in description.

Comment: The innermost SELECT return senseless result. `ingredient_id` returned isn't assosiated with MAX(flyer_items.price_weight) and choosed randomly from `ingredient_to_flyer_item` table.

Comment: How many rows in the subquery with the lengthy "create sort index"?

Comment: When you use a `group by` this most of the time implies sorting by the column.

Answer (score 1):

Each row in the `EXPLAIN`'s output having `NULL` in the 'key' column should be investigated. Those row marked as `(derivedN)` aren't the culprits but rather the victims. In your case `flyer_items` table need the indexes: `(id)`, `(flyer_id)`, `(id, flyer_id)` and `(flyer_id, id)`. I can't predict which one of the last two will be choosed by optimizer.

Then derived tables produced by `JOIN`s will get the suitable inherited indexes for further proceeding.

Comment: Thank you. All indexed suggestions were ignored though. The NULL in key column seems to be related to subqueries, but can't find why so far.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` shows that `flyer_items` have three keys `id_2`, `id` ,`flyer_id` unrelated to the query. Add the missed indexes and try again.

Comment: @JeffB.  I'm seriously amused with your case :) Can you explain the logic behind the query? What do you expect to get with innermost select?

Comment: Any way to reach to you? Skype: seozus

Comment: `(id), (flyer_id), (id, flyer_id) and (flyer_id, id).` -- the first two of these are redundant; don't add them unless they are `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can simplify your query, there is among other things a nested sum that I'm not sure which purpose it has. Here's one simplification of your query:

```
SELECT itr.recipe_id
     , SUM(itr.weight)
     , SUM(aprice_weight)
     , SUM(itr.weight+aprice_weight) AS score
FROM (
    SELECT itfin.id AS flyer_item_id
         , itfin.flyer_id
         , itfin.max_weight AS aprice_weight
         , itfin.ingredient_id
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX(price_weight) AS max_weight
             , flyer_items.id
             , flyer_items.flyer_id
             , ingredient_to_flyer_item.ingredient_id
        FROM flyer_items
        JOIN ingredient_to_flyer_item 
            ON flyer_items.id = ingredient_to_flyer_item.flyer_item_id
        WHERE flyer_items.flyer_id IN (2)
        GROUP BY ingredient_to_flyer_item.ingredient_id
               , flyer_items.flyer_id
               , flyer_items.id  -- full group by
    ) AS itfin
) AS itf
JOIN `ingredient_to_recipe` AS `itr` 
    ON `itf`.`ingredient_id` = `itr`.`ingredient_id`
GROUP BY `itr`.`recipe_id`
ORDER BY `score` DESC
LIMIT 12;
```

This can be further simplified:

```
SELECT itr.recipe_id
     , SUM(itr.weight)
     , SUM(max_weight)
     , SUM(itr.weight+max_weight) AS score
FROM (  
    SELECT MAX(price_weight) AS max_weight
         , flyer_items.id
         , flyer_items.flyer_id
         , ingredient_to_flyer_item.ingredient_id
    FROM flyer_items
    JOIN ingredient_to_flyer_item 
        ON flyer_items.id = ingredient_to_flyer_item.flyer_item_id
    WHERE flyer_items.flyer_id IN (2)
    GROUP BY ingredient_to_flyer_item.ingredient_id
           , flyer_items.flyer_id
           , flyer_items.id
) AS itf
JOIN ingredient_to_recipe AS itr
    ON itf.ingredient_id = itr.ingredient_id
GROUP BY itr.recipe_id
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 12;
```

Going through the JOIN predicates you may consider the following changes to your indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE ingredient_to_flyer_item
    ADD KEY (flyer_item_id);

ALTER TABLE `flyer_items` DROP KEY `id`;

ALTER TABLE `flyer_items` DROP KEY `flyer_id`;

ALTER TABLE flyer_items ADD UNIQUE KEY (flyer_id, id);
```

I did not have time to examine indexes very thoroughly though. Here's an EXPLAIN for the last query, with these changes on indexes:

```
+------+-------------+--------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table                    | type | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref                  | rows | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+--------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>               | ALL  | NULL          | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                 |   67 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | itr                      | ref  | ingredient_id | ingredient_id | 4       | itf.ingredient_id    |   30 |                                                 |
|    2 | DERIVED     | flyer_items              | ref  | id_2,flyer_id | flyer_id      | 4       | const                |   67 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    2 | DERIVED     | ingredient_to_flyer_item | ref  | flyer_item_id | flyer_item_id | 4       | test3.flyer_items.id |    1 |                                              |
+------+-------------+--------------------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

EDIT: possible simplification, remove flyer_items.id, flyer_items.flyer_id from SELECT and GROUP BY

```
SELECT itr.recipe_id
     , SUM(itr.weight)
     , SUM(max_weight)
     , SUM(itr.weight+max_weight) AS score
FROM (  
    SELECT MAX(price_weight) AS max_weight
         , ingredient_to_flyer_item.ingredient_id
    FROM flyer_items
    JOIN ingredient_to_flyer_item 
        ON flyer_items.id = ingredient_to_flyer_item.flyer_item_id
    WHERE flyer_items.flyer_id IN (2)
    GROUP BY ingredient_to_flyer_item.ingredient_id
) AS itf
JOIN ingredient_to_recipe AS itr
    ON itf.ingredient_id = itr.ingredient_id
GROUP BY itr.recipe_id
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 12;
```

Comment: Add (id, flyer_id) and (flyer_id, id) indexes to the `flyer_items` table.

Comment: (flyer_id, id) is already there (at least that's my intention with: `ALTER TABLE flyer_items ADD UNIQUE KEY (flyer_id, id);`). I added (id, flyer_id) as well, but as far as I can see the EXPLAIN is identical as without it

Comment: It's clear now. The innermost `SELECT` can't inherit any index from the used tables because of grouping.